# Опять опять

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Опять напьется()опять напишет.

Какой знак ставится в таких случаях?Возможна  постановка и тире и запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Опять напьется, опять напишет. Простая временная последовательность событий, перечислительная интонация.
2. Опять напьется - опять напишет. Обозначена причинно-следственная связь событий (условие - событие), разделительная интонация.
3. Опять - напьется, опять - напишет. Тоже временная последовательность событий, но при параллельной структуре предложений, авторский вариант. Дополнительно подчеркнута повторяемость происходящего.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Писатель - алкоголик?

Comment: Алкаш, сутяга и кляузник.

Comment: Забавный «спектакль одного слова».  1. Для разбора предлагается предложение с не очень ясным, но очень интригующим содержанием. 2. Предлагается  подробный разбор грамматической формы, никак эту интригу не проясняющий. 3. Следует пауза – зрители ждут дальнейших объяснений.  4. Наконец терпение кончается, и они начинают прояснять ситуацию сами.

Comment: Вполне логично в контексте Нового года.

Comment: Лучше вообще не употреблять подобные обороты, чтобы потом не морочить головы людям даже в "контексте Нового года".

Comment: Мне кажется, шутки нужны. Это риторический прием, который помогает немного отвлечься от очень серьезных грамматических разборов. Недаром же смайлики придумали, чтобы сделать беседу более душевной и эмоциональной. Только  шутки должны быть смешными, понятными и добрыми.

Comment: Это не было шуткой.Были интересны все варианты написания подобных фраз.В основе всего сложного - простота.Помните это.

Comment: Фразы я, разумеется, не считаю шуткой. Мне показались смешными только комментарии.

Comment: Ах,простите;)